# Different Values In Two SQL Tables

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to select different values from two tables in SQL but my code isn't working. The first part of it works:

```
SELECT distinct a.c1, b."Commodity.Code"::numeric FROM coletados a, commod b 
    WHERE a.c1 = b."Commodity.Code"::numeric
```

But when I try to select different values, it doesn't work. My entire SQL statement is:

```
SELECT * FROM commod b
    WHERE b."Commodity.Code"::numeric =! 
        (SELECT DISTINCT a.c1, b."Commodity.Code"::numeric 
            FROM coletados a, commod b
                WHERE a.c1 = b."Commodity.Code"::numeric)
```

In reality, I just want the column of numbers that are different in the two tables, so I don't need the '*', but I don't know if I can select the same variable (a.c1 or b."Commodity.Code") twice. Thanks for all the help.

Comment: What flavor or SQL is this?

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing one value to two values.  In Postgres, one method is:

```
select *
from commod b
where (b.c1, "Commodity.Code"::numeric) not in (select a.c1, a."Commodity.Code"::numeric
                                                from coletados a
                                               );
```

Or, using your approach:

```
select *
from commod b
where "Commodity.Code"::numeric not in (select a."Commodity.Code"::numeric
                                        from coletadoa a
                                        where a.c1 = b.c1
                                       );
```

That is, the subquery does not need a `join`, just a correlation clause.

Comment: Thank you very much, Gordon!